# Issue with saving extended User model

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I've been having trouble submitting a form that creates a user profile which is extended from auth.User after the user has been registered with Django-Register.

I get the error: `Please correct the following fields:` from a string of code in my template:

```
{% if form.errors %}<p>Please correct the following fields:</p>{% endif %}
```

that tells me if there's error in the form and the rest the rest of the form template looks like this:

```
<div class='register_div'>
  {% if form.first_name.errors %}
    <p class='error'>{{ form.first_name.errors }}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <p>
    <label for='first_name'{% if form.first_name.errors %}class='error'{% endif %}>
      First Name:
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>{{ form.first_name }}</p>
</div>
```

My models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
role = models.CharField(max_length=14, choices=role, verbose_name='Role', blank=True, null=True)
job_description = models.TextField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Job Description', blank=True)

# Basic Information
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='First Name')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Last Name')
dob = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of Birth')
stud_id = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Student ID',)
mob_num = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Mobile Number')
home_num = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Home Number')
term_add = models.TextField(verbose_name='Term Time Address')
perm_add = models.TextField(verbose_name='Permanent Address')
au_status = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Are you a member of the AU?')

# Next of Kin Details
nok_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='First Name (Next of Kin) ')
nok_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Last Name (Next of Kin)')
relationship = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Relationship (with Next of Kin)')
nok_mob_num = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Mobile Number (Next of Kin)')
nok_home_num = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Home Number (Next of Kin)')
nok_add = models.TextField(verbose_name='Address (Next of Kin)')

# Health and Safety
diet = models.TextField(verbose_name='Dietary Requirements', blank=True)
med_cond = models.TextField(verbose_name='Medical Conditions', blank=True)
fear = models.TextField(verbose_name='Greatest Fears', blank=True)
swim = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Can you swim more than 100m?')

# Equipment:
sleeping_bag = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Do you have a warm sleeping bag')
waterproof = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Do you have waterproof clothing?')
shoes = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Do you have a pair of climbing shoes?')
shoe_size = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='What is your athletic shoe size (in UK sizes)?', max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)
harness = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Do you have a harness?')
belay_device = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Do you have a belay plate and a screwgate?')
helmet = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Do you have a helmet?')
nut = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Do you have a set of nuts?')
hex = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Do you have a set of hexes?')

# Misc.:
minibus = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Can you drive the SU minibus?')
```

My forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):

# Basic Information
first_name = forms.RegexField(label='First Name', regex=r'^[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$',
             error_messages = {'invalid': "A name starts with a capital letter,
                     and may contain only alphabetical characters."})
last_name = forms.RegexField(label='Last Name', regex=r'^[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$',
        error_messages = {'invalid': "A name starts with a capital letter,
                    and may contain only alphabetical characters."} )

# Details
au_status = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Are you a member of the AU?', required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)

# Next of Kin Details
nok_first_name = forms.RegexField(label='First Name (Next of Kin)', regex=r'^[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$',
              error_messages = {'invalid': "A name starts with a capital letter, 
                          and may contain only alphabetical characters."})
nok_last_name = forms.RegexField(label='Last Name (Next of Kin)',
                         regex=r'^[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$',
                 error_messages = {'invalid': "A name starts with a capital
                         letter, and may contain only alphabetical characters."})

# Health and Safety
swim = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Can you swim more than 100m?',
               required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)

# Equipment:
sleeping_bag = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Do you have a warm sleeping bag', required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)
waterproof = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Do you have waterproof clothing?', required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)
shoes = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Do you have a pair of climbing shoes?', required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)
harness = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Do you have a harness?', required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)
belay_device = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Do you have a belay plate and a screwgate?', required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)
helmet = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Do you have a helmet?', required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)
nut = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Do you have a set of nuts?', required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)
hex = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Do you have a set of hexes?', required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)

# Misc.:
minibus = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Can you drive the SU minibus?', required=False, choices=choices, coerce=int)

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
```

My views.py

```
def MemberRegistration(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
        profile = UserProfile(user=user)  
        profile.first_name      = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        profile.last_name       = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        profile.dob             = form.cleaned_data['dob']
        profile.stud_id         = form.cleaned_data['stud_id']
        profile.mob_num         = form.cleaned_data['mob_num']
        profile.home_num        = form.cleaned_data['home_num']
        profile.term_add        = form.cleaned_data['term_add']
        profile.perm_add        = form.cleaned_data['perm_add']
        profile.au_status       = form.cleaned_data['au_status']
        profile.nok_first_name  = form.cleaned_data['nok_first_name']
        profile.nok_last_name   = form.cleaned_data['nok_last_name']
        profile.relationship    = form.clenaed_data['relationship']
        profile.nok_mob_num     = form.cleaned_data['nok_mob_num']
        profile.nok_home_num    = form.cleaned_data['nok_home_num']
        profile.nok_add         = form.cleaned_data['nok_add']
        profile.diet            = form.cleaned_data['diet']
        profile.med_cond        = form.cleaned_data['med_cond']
        profile.fear            = form.cleaned_data['fear']
        profile.swim            = form.cleaned_data['swim']
        profile.sleeping_bag    = form.cleaned_data['sleeping_bag']
        profile.waterproof      = form.cleaned_data['waterproof']
        profile.shoes           = form.cleaned_data['shoes']
        profile.shoe_size       = form.cleaned_data['shoe_size']
        profile.harness         = form.cleaned_data['harness']
        profile.belay_device    = form.cleaned_data['belay_device']
        profile.helmet          = form.cleaned_data['helmet']
        profile.nut             = form.cleaned_data['nut']
        profile.hex             = form.cleaned_data['hex']
        profile.minibus         = form.cleaned_data['minibus']  
        profile.save()
        return render_to_response('base_profile.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('base_registration.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form = RegistrationForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('base_registration.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`
```

Any help is much appreciated! It would be great if anyone could tell me how to cut down on the code as well as I find to be excessive. Thanks for all your help :)

Updated:

I know what's the error! [Refer to this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516437/django-form-has-no-errors-but-form-is-valid-doesnt-validate?rq=1) I didn't fill in the user field of the model. Can anyone help me with that and reducing the amount of code I use?

Update 2:

The form gets passed now, but there's always an error.

I get `IntegrityError at /register/ - accounts_userprofile.first_name may not be NULL` for the line `profile.save()` when I use this version of my views.py

```
`if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
            user.first_name     = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name      = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.save()
            profile = UserProfile(user=user,
            dob             = form.cleaned_data['dob'],
            stud_id         = form.cleaned_data['stud_id'],
            mob_num         = form.cleaned_data['mob_num'],
            home_num        = form.cleaned_data['home_num'],
            term_add        = form.cleaned_data['term_add'],
            perm_add        = form.cleaned_data['perm_add'],
            au_status       = form.cleaned_data['au_status'],
            nok_first_name  = form.cleaned_data['nok_first_name'],
            nok_last_name   = form.cleaned_data['nok_last_name'],
            relationship    = form.cleaned_data['relationship'],
            nok_mob_num     = form.cleaned_data['nok_mob_num'],
            nok_home_num    = form.cleaned_data['nok_home_num'],
            nok_add     = form.cleaned_data['nok_add'],
            diet            = form.cleaned_data['diet'],
            med_cond        = form.cleaned_data['med_cond'],
            fear            = form.cleaned_data['fear'],
            swim            = form.cleaned_data['swim'],
            sleeping_bag    = form.cleaned_data['sleeping_bag'],
            waterproof      = form.cleaned_data['waterproof'],
            shoes           = form.cleaned_data['shoes'],
            shoe_size       = form.cleaned_data['shoe_size'],
            harness         = form.cleaned_data['harness'],
            belay_device    = form.cleaned_data['belay_device'],
            helmet          = form.cleaned_data['helmet'],
            nut             = form.cleaned_data['nut'],
            hex             = form.cleaned_data['hex'],
            minibus         = form.cleaned_data['minibus'],
            )
           profile.save()`
```

If I use this versions of views.py instead:

```
if form.is_valid():
        profile = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

        for key in UserProfileForm.base_fields.keys():
            for val in form.cleaned_data.values():
                setattr(profile, key, val)

        profile.save()

        return render_to_response('base_profile.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))`
```

I get passed to base_profile.html with only first_name and last_name being filled up with either the term_add/perm_add/nok_add/diet/med_cond/fears fields. Can anyone help? Sorry for being such a noob >.<

My old views.py that was used to register User and UserProfile at once that worked looked like this:

```
def MemberRegistration(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render_to_response('base_profile.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(username        = form.cleaned_data['username'],    
                                        email           = form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                        password        = form.cleaned_data['password'],
                                        )
        user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name  = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        member = user.save()
        member = Member(user=user,  first_name      = form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                                    last_name       = form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                                    date_of_birth   = form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'],
                                    email           = form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                    student_id      = form.cleaned_data['student_id'],
                                    au_status       = form.cleaned_data['au_status'],
                                    mob_num         = form.cleaned_data['mob_num'],
                                    home_num        = form.cleaned_data['home_num'],
                                    term_time_add   = form.cleaned_data['term_time_add'],
                                    permanent_add   = form.cleaned_data['permanent_add'],
                                    diet            = form.cleaned_data['diet'],
                                    med_condition   = form.cleaned_data['med_condition'],
                                    fear            = form.cleaned_data['fear'],
                                    swim            = form.cleaned_data['swim'],
                                    sleeping_bag    = form.cleaned_data['sleeping_bag'],
                                    waterproof      = form.cleaned_data['waterproof'],
                                    shoes           = form.cleaned_data['shoes'],
                                    shoe_size       = form.cleaned_data['shoe_size'],
                                    harness         = form.cleaned_data['harness'],
                                    belay_device    = form.cleaned_data['belay_device'],
                                    helmet          = form.cleaned_data['helmet'],
                                    nuts_set        = form.cleaned_data['nuts_set'],
                                    hexes_set       = form.cleaned_data['hexes_set'],
                                    minibus_driver  = form.cleaned_data['minibus_driver'],
                                    )

        member.save()
        return render_to_response('base_profile.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('base_registration.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form = RegistrationForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('base_registration.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You already have the user in 'request.user', why look it up again?

Answer (score 0):

for the view you can reduce it doing something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)  # you already have the user in the request.

    for key, val in form.cleaned_data.values():
        setattr(profile, key, val)

    profile.save()
```

Here you are iterating over the dictionary and setting all the keys and values to the profile object. Please check that all the keys are needed, if not you will have to remove them somehow or try a different approach, for example:

```
my_keys = ('key1', 'key2', 'key3', ...)
for key in my_keys:
    profile[key] = form.cleaned_data.get(key, "")

profile.save()
```

Also you should use  model forms:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user',)
```

Also the user model from django already have a first_name, last_name fields so you don't need to add those again.

I can see you also have a lot of fields on your model, I would suggest you to create a model like this:

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)        

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This way you can save all the details and more in a more flexible way instead of having a huge amount of fields for the user. you can get it a lot more interesting and add a type and a function to convert it (for example if you need the value to be an integer).

so for example instead of adding fields to the `UserProfile` class like `home_num` or `diet`  you could do something like this:

```
for key, value in form.cleaned_data.values():
    UserDetails(user=request.user, name=key, value=value).save()
```

and then just access any:

```
print request.user.user_details_set.all()
```

and it should print all these details. The only bad thing I can see from this approach is that `ModelForms` will not work that easily but I assure you that migrations be more sporadic :)

Comment: The problem is that I've already created the user previously and I shouldn't get him/her to type in the username etc. again. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: ok just updated the answer, the problem is you are doing a erroneous query to get the user as @möter said

Comment: Do I still have to add the user fields to the form?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error saying that the user field is required >.<

Comment: oh, you should use model forms there, you need to exclude that field from the meta. just updating

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! Could you further explain how to simplify the model as I don't really understand how it works?

Comment: sure I'll rephrase. and welcome to stack overflow! if you have a chance take a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette) section