# Form not being submitted

Tags: python, django, django-forms

It was all fine just an hour ago but now when I try to add data to form and save it is running the `exception` part
Before the post method was called and the form used to save and redirect

But I cannot figure out why the exception part is running.
I haven't change anything
In console it is giving `"POST /forum/topics/9/reply HTTP/1.1" 200 523`

```
class NewPostView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = NewPostForm
    template_name = 'forum/new_post.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if 'pk' not in context:
            context['pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form = self.get_form()
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.topic = topic
                post.created_by = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
                post.save()
                return redirect('topic-detail', pk=topic.pk)

        except Exception as e:
            messages.warning(request, "Failed To Create. Error: {}".format(e))
            messages.warning(request, "Failed To Create Check Errors")
            args = {'form': form, 'pk': self.kwargs['pk']}
            #print(args)
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Edit:Now I can see `User matching query does not exist.` error

Edit2 : Thank you all for the response. I found the error that I had made, I was actually using `django.contrib.auth.user` in the login while I  was using my own `User` model.
When I change   `created_by = models.ForeignKey("auth.User"),` in the model then it worked fine.

Comment: Don't use blanket (or very "broad") exceptions! Try to do this *without* the `try`-`except`, and if `DEBUG` is set on `TRUE`, Django will post a traceback as response.

Comment: could you please share the error messages?

Comment: @AnuvratParashar There isn't any error it is just giving `"POST /forum/topics/9/reply HTTP/1.1" 200 523`

Comment: @BishwaKarki if you say that the except block was executed, there must have been an exception. could you follow the steps Willem outlined and post the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django - form has no errors but form.is\_valid() doesn't validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516437/django-form-has-no-errors-but-form-is-valid-doesnt-validate)

Comment: @AnuvratParashar  Now I can see this error 
`{'form': <NewTopicForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(subject;message)>, 'view': <forum.views.NewForm object at 0x7f3085d71cc0>}
{'form': <NewTopicForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(subject;message)>, 'view': <forum.views.NewForm object at 0x7f3085d71cc0>, 'pk': 2}
[01/Oct/2018 07:36:12] "GET /forum/board/2/new_form HTTP/1.1" 200 668
{'form': <NewTopicForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(subject;message)>, 'pk': 2}
[01/Oct/2018 07:36:21] "POST /forum/board/2/new_form HTTP/1.1" 200 687
`
There is valid=unknown and bound=false

Comment: remove the try-except block and then run.
that should tell you what went wrong. Also, adding more information to the question is the preferred instead of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are no longer logged into the application, so `request.user.pk` is `None`.

The easiest way to ensure only a logged in user can access your view is to add the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class NewPostView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
```

Comment: When I tried using the user that is logged in it gave the same error

Comment: What do you mean by "using the user that is logged in"? `request.user` is always the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your views.py

```
class NewPostView(View):
    .....add your template_name, form_class and get function....

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=self.kwargs['pk']) # here you can directly add pk=pk and def post(self, request, pk)
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
       post = form.save(commit=False)
       post.topic = topic
       post.created_by = self.request.user
       post.save()
       return redirect('topic-detail', pk=topic.pk)
    else:
       messages.error(request, "Error Message")
       return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

For not logged in user, you can follow Daniel's answer and/or in your template you can add,

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
 html
{% else %}
 html
{% endif %}
```