# how do i save a user to a database in DJANGO using request.method == 'POST'?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a role-based sign up pages for a *jobseeker* and a *recruiter*. Form handling is based on `role` when a user clicks up when registering.

I have an issue with registering a user: when I do `POST` request it doesn't save a user to my database.

my role.html :

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Choose A Role{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
  <div class="w-full max-w-md">
    <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold mb-4 text-center">Register by your role</h1>
    <p class="text-center">Choose the right role for you to enter our site</p>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'core:role' %}" class="bg-amber-100 grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 w-full max-w-screen-sm">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <div class="flex items-center">
        <input type="radio" id="jobseeker1" name="role" value="jobseeker">
        <label class="w-full px-6 py-8 rounded-lg shadow-md bg-white border-2 border-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white cursor-pointer transition-colors duration-300" for="jobseeker1">
          <span class="text-xl font-bold uppercase">I'm a Jobseeker</span>
          <ul class="text-sm mt-2">
            <li>
              i want to apply for jobs
            </li>
          </ul>
          </label>
      </div>

      <div class="flex items-center">
        <input type="radio" id="recruiter2" name="role" value="recruiter">
        <label class="w-full px-6 py-8 rounded-lg shadow-md bg-white border-2 border-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white cursor-pointer transition-colors duration-300" for="recruiter2">
          <span class="text-xl font-bold uppercase">I'm a Recruiter</span>
          <ul class="text-sm mt-2">
            <li>
              i want to post jobs
            </li>
          </ul>
          </label>
      </div>


      <div class="flex mx-auto py-5 justify-items-center">
        <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline justify-items-center" type="submit">
          Continue to your role
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

here is an example of a job seeker registration page:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block title%}JobSeeker{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="w-1/2 my-6 mx-auto p-6 bg-gray-100 rounded-xl"> 
    <h1 class="mb-6 text-3xl">Job Seeker Registration.</h1>

    <form action="." method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="inline-block mb-2">First name</label><br>
        {{ form.first_name }}
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="inline-block mb-2">Last name</label><br>
        {{ form.last_name }}
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="inline-block mb-2">Email</label><br>
        {{ form.email }}
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="inline-block mb-2">Password</label><br>
        {{ form.password1 }}
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="inline-block mb-2">Repeat password</label><br>
        {{ form.password2 }}
      </div>

      {% if form.errors or form.non_field_errors %}
      <div class="mb-3 p-6 bg-red-100 rounded-xl">
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.errors }}
        {% endfor %}

        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
      </div>
      {% endif %}

      <button class="py-4 px-8 text-lg bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-700 rounded-xl text-white" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my views.py:

```py
def role(request):
    selected_role = request.POST.get('role')
    if selected_role == 'jobseeker':

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = JobseekerForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

                return redirect('/login/')
        else:
            form = JobseekerForm()

        return render(request, 'core/jobseeker_register.html', {
            "form": form
        })

    elif selected_role == 'recruiter':

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RecruiterForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

                return redirect('/login/')
        else:
            form = RecruiterForm()

        return render(request, 'core/recruiter_register.html', {
            "form": form
        })
    else:
        return render(request, 'core/role.html')
```

I already tried splitting this view into separate views for *jobseeker* and *recruiter*, but I couldn't get it to work because everytime i did this it didnt even show the form fields. So for now i decided to keep everything inside the single *role view*.

The form on the page works fine but nothing is saved to DB.

Comment: `now iwant to show different pages` please rephrase your question. It is currently unclear whether you're asking about page design or backend request handlers implementation.

Comment: For debugging purpose try [showing form validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516437/django-form-has-no-errors-but-form-is-valid-doesnt-validate)

Comment: its the backend side , i have 2 sign up pages one for job seekers and one for recruiters , you see the code of role.html ? that allows a user to  choose a role before registering, i have defined the role view  which is the code above .. this code does take a user to their respective role sign up page, the problem starts when a user has submitted their sign up details , my role view doesnt save that user to the database and no it doesnt show any error when the form is submitted.

Comment: Removed all the not relevant text about template design from the post. Once again, please follow the link above and edit your template to see _form validation errors_: `{{ form.errors }} {{ form.non_field_errors }}`. If form is not valid `if recruiter_form.is_valid():` _saving_ will not happen.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. `text about template design` I removed words about _"I want to design page the other way but it does not work"_ since this is not related to saving to db problem. The template code itself with the form code helps understanding the solution and should stay. Sorry if I confused you and this forced you to remove the template code.

Comment: i have updated the text with more code from  one of the signup pages which is jobseeker template could you take a look at it , see if theres something iam missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David Wenzel made me think about how i should have structured my views for this issue i had.. it was something so simple , i finally got it to work role views :

```
def role(request):
selected_role = request.POST.get('role')
if selected_role == 'jobseeker':
    return redirect('/jobseeker_register/')
elif selected_role == 'recruiter':
    return redirect('/recruiter_register/')
else:
    return render(request, 'core/role.html')
```

```
def jobseeker_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JobseekerForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/login/')

    form = JobseekerForm()

    return render(request, 'core/jobseeker_register.html', {
        "form": form
    })


def recruiter_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RecruiterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/login/')

    form = RecruiterForm()

    return render(request, 'core/recruiter_register.html', {
        "form": form
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

after the first POST it should complain about the form (JobseekerForm/RecruiterForm) beeing invalid and the second POST request where it is supposed to save the form doesn't have the selected_role anymore and it never gets there

you could just change the first form to GET and it should work

> I already tried splitting this view into separate views for jobseeker and recruiter, but I couldn't get it to work because everytime i did this it didnt even show the form field

that is pretty strange - if the template works in you single view it has to work on its own

Comment: just tried the get method it still doesnt save a user, if you were to separate the views how would you go about it ?

Comment: start with a view for each form and test If its working -  quick way to check If certain points are reached is to add print statements

Comment: Thank you,  after following what you said I tried everything in separating the views and it worked 